# how to make css inside useEffect?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

How to make css inside useEffect? I want to make the About, Experience, Project, and Connect text yellow when my screen scrolls up
[image: this is my NavBar]

File NavBar.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
// import logo from '../assets/img/logo.svg';
import navIcon1 from '../assets/img/nav-icon1.svg';
// import navIcon2 from '../assets/img/nav-icon2.svg';
import navIcon3 from '../assets/img/nav-icon3.svg';
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

export const NavBar = () => {

  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState('home');
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const box = document.querySelector('nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover', 'nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active');
    box.style.color = '#64ffda !important';
    const onScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        setScrolled(true);
      } else {
        box.style.color = '#64ffda !important';
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [])

  const onUpdateActiveLink = (value) => {
    setActiveLink(value);
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar expand="md" className={scrolled ? "scrolled" : ""}>
        <Container>
          {/* <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
          </Navbar.Brand> */}
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </Navbar.Toggle>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ms-auto">
              {/* <Nav.Link href="#home" className={activeLink === 'home' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('home')}>Home</Nav.Link> */}
              <Nav.Link href="#about" className={activeLink === 'about' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('abouts')}>About</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#experience" className={activeLink === 'experience' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('experiences')}>Experience</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#project" className={activeLink === 'project' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('projects')}>Projects</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#connect" className={activeLink === 'connect' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('connect')}>Connect</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <span className="navbar-text">
              <div className="social-icon">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src={navIcon1} alt="" /></a>
                {/* <a href="#"><img src={navIcon2} alt="" /></a> */}
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src={navIcon3} alt="" /></a>
              </div>
              <HashLink to=''>
                <button className="vvd"><span>Resume</span></button>
              </HashLink>
            </span>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

File .css

```
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #64ffda !important;
}
```

I've added code like this to useEffect

```
const box = document.querySelector('nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover', 'nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link. navbar-link.active');
box. style. color = '#64ffda !important';
```

but, i got this error

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

Firstly, `querySelector` will only ever return a single matching element, while you want it to restyle all the links in your navigation bar.

Secondly, the selectors available to [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#syntax) are a subset of those available to CSS; [some pseudoclasses are not supported or behave differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors#selectors) – including `:hover`.

It's also worth pointing out that `querySelector` only takes a single string argument rather than a list of selector strings.

All in all – `querySelector` isn't a great fit for what you want to do here.

However – since you're already switching a `scrolled` class on the `NavBar` component, you can remove the `querySelector` code altogether, and just add some extra style rules to your css file:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        setScrolled(true);
      } else {
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [])
```

```css
/* Add .scrolled to the existing rule ... */
nav.navbar.scrolled .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover,
nav.navbar.scrolled .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #64ffda !important;
}

/* ... and add new rules for the non-.scrolled case */
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this really helped me. but after i followed your instructions, when my screen scroll up my hover also become white. I want the hover color to stay #64ffda

Comment: however, thanks to your directions I was able to find a way by adding it like this `nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover { /* nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active { */   color: #64ffda !important; }`